# Why do I get munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer Aborted when using qsort() function?

Tags: c++, pointers, qsort

I got this error "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer Aborted" when I using qsort() to sort a array that contains class objects.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

class MyString : public string
{
 public:
    MyString(const char *str) :string(str) {}
    MyString(const string & str) :string(str) {}
};

int CompareString(const void * e1, const void * e2)
{
    MyString * s1 = (MyString *) e1;
    MyString * s2 = (MyString *) e2;
    if ( *s1 < *s2 ) return -1;
    else if ( *s1 == *s2 ) return 0;
    else if ( *s1 > *s2 ) return 1; 
}

int main()
{
    MyString SArray[4] = {"big","me","about","take"};
    qsort(SArray,4,sizeof(MyString), CompareString);
    for( int i = 0;i < 4;++i )
        cout << SArray[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I comment out the qsort() line. The error disappears. I want to know why this happened and how to solve the error.

My output:

> me
>
> abo
>
> bi
>
> take
>
> munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
>
> Aborted

Comment: Try `(const MyString *)`.

Answer (score 2):

`qsort` works by copying elements around, but it does so by calling `memcpy`.  This is undefined behaviour for non-POD types (such as `std::string`), hence your crash.

Solution: use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) instead, which is the C++ way of sorting things.